# prepareforsegue vs performwithsegue if statements.

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have a table view, how would i go about creating code to have one cell go to one view controller and then have another cell to a second view controller.  Specifically the prepare for segue and perform with segue if statements.

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: I'm asking because i am unsure how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent view controller (where the table view lives) should have your UITableViewDelegate methods.

You'll need to create your own implementation of:

[`optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

And in there (which gets called when a cell is pressed), you'll want to call

[`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Load View", sender: self)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)

One of the parameters passed into didSelectRowAtIndexPath is the index path row, so you know which row the user pressed.  And you can pass along that cell (or the information, or the object that the cell is drawing it's contents from) in the "`sender`" parameter of the performSegueWithIdentifier method.

You'll have direct access to the child view controller from the parent in the [`prepareForSegue:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) method.  So you can do something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view

        let cellData = sender as YourDataObject

        let childViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourChildViewController

        // and now you can directly set whatever custom fields / bits
        // you need to set in your destination view controller
    }
}
```

Makes sense so far?

Comment: mostly.  What would the purpose of the optional function be?  can't i just implement the code directly in the table view controller already?                      I understand the if statement with prepare for segue, but how would i implement that with perform with segue?

Comment: A table view controller is a subclass of a regular view controller.  When "`performWithSegue`" is called, `prepareForSegue` is your chance to directly pass info from your [`sourceViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/sourceViewController) to the segue's [`destinationViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController)

Comment: so if i didn't need to pass any info to the following view controller, would i need to use the prepare for segue function?

Comment: @JonGardocki, no, you don't need to implement prepareForSegue if you don't need to pass any data to the destination view controller.